# Using Haar features for cascade object detector MATLAB

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, matlab-cvst, viola-jones, cascade-classifier

I am trying to use the `vision.cascadeObjectDetector` (MATLAB) to detect heads from a CCTV footage(and not faces).  Till now, I have tried the following:

1. Used `vision.cascadeObjectDetector` to detect faces.
2. trained it to detect a sign (an example shown in read me file)
3. created a folder with positive & negative training HEAD images & same for testing
4. tried to create a .mat file using `trainingImageLabeler` (although it gave me an error when trying to pass it as param to the object detector).

Can someone try to put me in the right track, to start detecting heads using Viola-Jones Haar features please?

Comment: What was the error message that you got?  Keep in mind that `trainCscadeObjectDetector` does not take a mat file, but an array of structures as the positiveIntstances parameter.